# How to ask an opinion question before starting to build a website

Tags: discussion

I will be building a new website, and I am about to ask what is the best language that suits such a model (I will also be stating what I am trying to do).

Is asking such a question permitted here?

Comment: No, opinion-based questions are strictly off-topic here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can i ask it on stackoverflow.com?

Comment: You can ask it in the chat (for example in the [HTML/CSS/Web Design room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign))

Comment: Straight from the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):  **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: By *"here"* I mean the whole Stack Exchange network. So: no.

Answer (score 6):

No.

That's what's commonly referred to as Bikeshedding. The specific question you're asking is also a [common form of procrastination](http://blog.codinghorror.com/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect/).

Those are two reasons why we don't allow such questions.  While debating the color of the bikeshed feels like progress, it isn't.  We want Stack Overflow to be a place where progress is made and the result of that progress can be shared with others.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a question is going to be off topic on all SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

**How?** Don't

**Is asking such a question permitted here?** No

Language recommendations are off-topic.
You may get some traction at Software-Rec stackexchange.
Software-rec traditionally had* a very high bar of quality for how to ask, so i recommend [checking their meta first](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

---

* (it's been a while since I was active there)

Comment: why not? I think it would be very nice.

Comment: It is a good fun question to ask on a Forum. You'll get great and interesting responses. Stackexchange is not a forum. Questions on stack-exchange should be answerable, not discuss-able.  Questions that work well are ones which have a clear, nonsubjective answer. But deciding on any kind of general language for a task never will -- otherwise only one language would exist for the task.
SE knows it is not a Forum, and doen't try to be one. It is left to the reader to find themselves a nice discussion forum to chat at. There are hundreds.

Comment: On most SE site recommendations are banned, but on Software Rec SE they are allowed. Software Rec SE, tries to lock down the subjectivity by demanding that  questions lay out a clear set of criteria that the answer can be objectively marked on.

Comment: Example of a question getting closed for not meeting the guidelines: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19121/software-to-create-work-breakdown-structures-from-an-ms-project-file

Comment: @BSMP: Or a more subtle question (with assocated meta on why) for not meeting guidelines: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/767/looking-for-first-person-physics-based-puzzle-games